Run a file from the users downloads folder
I am building a script to cleanup certain temp folders and then run a install.exe file.
I have the cleaning of temp folders all working but cannot get the exe to run.
Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    Dim oFSO, strAppData, objShell
    objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each sf In oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users").SubFolders
        sf = oFSO.BuildPath(sf.Path, "Downloads\")
       
        If oFSO.FolderExists(sf) Then Shell("test.exe")

    Next
End Sub`

I tried using the same way I was deleting the temp folders to locate the downloads folder and run the test.exe file but no luck

You're missing the username when building the path to the downloads folder. It's C:\Users\UserName\Downloads, not C:\Users\Downloads.

@KenWhite Hi Ken thank you for the reply. Would that not make it only work on the one users profile? I am trying to make this work on any pc i put it on.

I was able to get it working!
Dim usernamepath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
    Dim thefolder = usernamepath + "\Downloads"
    Dim startInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(thefolder & "\test.exe")
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = usernamepath + "\Downloads"
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo)


May I introduce you to Path.Combine? It automatically adds the path separator character, so there's no need to wonder if you need to:  Dim theFolder = Path.Combine(usernamePath, "Downloads"). (Also, the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is &, not +.)
